# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest IMS Path + Credentials

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest, ims

I have some problems passing an IMS url to my powershell command invoke-webrequest

```
http://ims-bs:7001/si/viewrevision?projectName=/blabla/project.pj&selection=my%5fsoftware%5fv1.1.zip
```

1.Right now I am stuck at &. I get an error even if I wrap the & with "&".

2.Also how can I directly pass credentials if the link would work?

Thank you!

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwRnH.png)

Comment: Please could you provide further details, such as the error message(s) that you're seeing  so that we can better assist you with your issue.

Comment: Hi i've added a screenshot of the error thrown out. The ims link contains a /project.pj&selection=myfile.zip.

Comment: The first query item after the last `/` should be a `?` (eg: `/project.pj?selection=myfile.zip`). Do a search, any search on google and look at the URL. Notice that the first query element start with a `?` and subsequent elements with `&`. You need to respect that scheme.

Comment: @Lodes, it looks like you're passing the URL without quotes around it like this: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://ims-bs:7001/si/viewrevision?projectName=/blabla/project.pj&selection=my%5fsoftware%5fv1.1.zip`, whereas you should wrap the URL like this": `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://ims-bs:7001/si/viewrevision?projectName=/blabla/project.pj&selection=my%5fsoftware%5fv1.1.zip"`